# Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked through the other posts about this and have tried adapted the strategies that were recommend by using Set ActiveWorkbook and Set Active Worksheet and I still get the same error.  I hope another set of eyes can help out as I am still very new to VBA and I am not all that comfortable with it yet.

Basically the idea is to copy the cells from column f to column j as values as long as the cells of F do not match the cells of J. I get the row count of column E and use that as my count in the for loop.

Code is here:

```
Private Sub CalculateRewards_Click()
    CopyPaste
End Sub

Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim i As Integer


     n = Sheets("Calculate").Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
     i = n

     For Counter = 1 To n

         Set curCell = Sheets("Calculate").Range("F2:F" &i)
         If "$F" &i <> "$J" &i Then
             Sheets("Calculate").Range("$F:$F" &i).Copy
             Sheets("Calculate").Range("$J:$J" &i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
             Application.CutCopyMode = False
          End If

          i = i + 1
      Next Counter

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help

Also Edit:
Link to Excel Sheet that has a before page, after first transaction sheet ,and a after second transaction sheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2mn0zyrtoscjin/Rewards.xlsm

Comment: The second `Dim` statement does not have a variable, is that where you're declaring `i`?

Comment: Also, it looks like you need to do some string interpolation. VBA does not support dropping `i` into quotes the way you have above: you'll need to use the `&` operator, like `.Range("F2:F" & i)`

Comment: @Dan Wagner, the first comment is a whoops transposing error.  I accidently deleted teh i when I was formatting the code.  I will try the second comment now

Comment: Ok added the string interpolation still error, but at least it will function(hopefully) when the function eventually runs

Answer (score 2):

CHange this:

```
     Set curCell = Sheets("Calculate").Range("F2:F" &i)
     If "$F" &i <> "$J" &i Then
         Sheets("Calculate").Range("$F:$F" &i).Copy
         Sheets("Calculate").Range("$J:$J" &i).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
         Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End If
```

To this:

```
     Set curCell = Sheets("Calculate").Range("F2:F" & i)
      If curCell <> Sheets("Calculate").Range("$J" & i) Then
         Sheets("Calculate").Range("$J:$J" &i).Value = curCell.Value
      End If
```

May need to do some more teaking as I notice you're working with `SpecialCells` which essentially filters the range, so iterating `For i = 1 to n...` probably does not work.  Maybe something like:

```
    Dim rngCalc as Range
    Set rngCalc = Sheets("Calculate").Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For each curCell in rngCalc.Cells
        If curCell <> curCell.Offset(0, 4) Then
            curCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = curCell.Value
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `.SpecialCells` filtering that is occurring

Comment: This works and doesnt at the same time.  The last part of code you recommended takes column E and copies it to column J.  The second part gives me runtime error 13, but this could be that I am not copying and removing the right things.  I give it +1 because it does work though

Comment: Debugging gets error at `If curCell <> Sheets("Calculate").Range("$J" & i) Then'

Comment: Try `If curCell.Value <> Sheets("Calculate").Range("$J" & i).Value`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** this sub will calculate the points for the last transaction (identified as the furthest-right column containing transactions) and write them down in column C.

```
Option Explicit
Sub UpdateCurrentPurchase()

Dim CalcSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastTransRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
Dim LastTransCol As Long, LastTransRow As Long
Dim PurchaseArray() As Variant
Dim Points As Long, Index As Long

'set references up-front
Set CalcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculate")
With CalcSheet
    LastTransCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column '<~ find the last column
    LastTransRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastTransCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Set LastTransRange = .Range(.Cells(2, LastTransCol), .Cells(LastTransRow, LastTransCol))
    Set TargetRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(LastTransRow, 6)) '<~ column F is the Current Purchase Col
    LastTransRange.Copy Destination:=TargetRange '<~ copy last transactions to Current Purchase Col
End With

'pull purchases into a variant array
PurchaseArray = TargetRange

'calculate points
For Index = 1 To LastTransRow
    Points = Int(PurchaseArray(Index, 1) / 10) '<~ calculate points
    CalcSheet.Cells(Index + 1, 3) = Points '<~ write out the points amount in col C
Next Index

End Sub
```

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE:** I think the below will get you where you're going. That being said, it seems like simply overwriting column J with column F (as values) might be the fastest way to an acceptable answer, so if that's the case we can re-work this code to be much quicker using `Range` objects.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CalculateRewards_Click()
    CopyPaste
End Sub

Sub CopyPaste()

Dim LastRow As Long, Counter As Long
Dim cSheet As Worksheet '<~ add a worksheet reference to save some typing

'set references up front
Set cSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculate")
With cSheet
    LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<~ set loop boundary

    'loop that compares the value in column 6 (F) to the value in
    'column 10 (J) and writes the value from F to J if they are not equal
    For Counter = 1 To LastRow
        If .Cells(Counter, 6).Value <> .Cells(Counter, 10).Value Then
            .Cells(Counter, 10) = .Cells(Counter, 6)
        End If
    Next Counter
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works beautifully.  I really appreciate the comments so I know what is going on. Thanks for the effort.  I post this on a forum a few days ago then I post it on Stack and I get an answer in less than an hour on Stack and I am still waiting on forum> Stack FTW

Comment: Basically it works, but when I change the value in F it changes it in J.  What I wanted was after it runs, and I change F, then it would copy the updated value into K

Comment: Hmm... so you would need it to run in "phases" I suppose? Column J could be populated with formulas that ensure it always reflects Column F, then your button code could overwrite Column J with values only. Does that sound right?

Comment: in not sure I follow.  I guess I was using the not equal operator to know to skip on to the next column if the previous column shipped. Do I guess I should add the rest of the columns to the range and add a bunch of if else statements?

Comment: Haha this sort of miscommunication happens sometimes. Can you provide a sample of what the results should be?

Comment: Yeah do you want a link to a dropbox or do you want me to post it in the question?

Comment: I would link to it in the question, that way other folks can have a crack at it